# Class does not contain contstructor error

Tags: c#, class, oop

I'm relatively new to programming and I've just gotten into classes.
The problem is, my compiler is returning

> "Error    1   'OlioohjelmoinninPerusteet.Blogimerkinta' does not contain a
>   constructor that takes 1 arguments"

I have no idea how to fix this, here's my code.

```
using System;
namespace OlioohjelmoinninPerusteet
{
    class Blogimerkinta
    {
        string teksti;
        string[] avainsanat;

        public string Teksti { get; set; }
        public string[] Avainsanat { get; set; }
    }

    class Ohjelma
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string otsikko = "Otsikko";
            Blogimerkinta merkinta = new Blogimerkinta(otsikko);
            merkinta.Teksti = "Teksti";
            merkinta.Avainsanat = new string[] { "Eka", "Toka" };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this Japanese language? Just wondering!

Comment: OMG!!!! 9 answers and still counting ...

Comment: @Rahul Not sure what it is, but it's not japanese. And yes... the amount of people that pounced on this question is astounding. More than half of them are 1K+

Comment: @gitsitgo It's finnish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[By default, if you do not specify a constructor it is the same as below](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx)

> If you do not provide a constructor for your object, C# will create
>   one by default that instantiates the object and sets member variables
>   to the default values as listed in Default Values Table (C#
>   Reference).

[Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173115%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> A constructor that takes no parameters is called a default
>   constructor. Default constructors are invoked whenever an object is
>   instantiated by using the new operator and no arguments are provided
>   to new.
>
> Unless the class is static, classes without constructors are given a
>   public default constructor by the C# compiler in order to enable class
>   instantiation.

```
class Blogimerkinta
{
    string teksti;
    string[] avainsanat;

    public string Teksti { get; set; }
    public string[] Avainsanat { get; set; }
    public Blogimerkinta()
    {
    }
}
```

You are calling a constructor that was not specified, namely

```
    public Blogimerkinta(string TADA)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are newing up an object and passing in a parameter for the constructor:

```
Blogimerkinta merkinta = new Blogimerkinta(otsikko);
```

this object does not have a constructor that takes any arguments, by default you can use the default constructor all c# objects get with no parameters:

```
Blogimerkinta merkinta = new Blogimerkinta();
```

or create a constructor that takes a string argument:

```
public Blogimerkinta(string arg) 
{
    //use argument for something
}
```

Comment: You get a +1 despite your use of "newing up". Verbing weirds language.

Comment: Just your standard programming jargon =)

Comment: Your explanation is in English but examples are in Japanese language. that's not acceptable. :)

Comment: The examples are in finnish though, @Rahul

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a constructor for your class like this:

```
class Blogimerkinta
{
    string teksti;
    string[] avainsanat;

    public string Teksti { get; set; }
    public string[] Avainsanat { get; set; }

    public Blogimerkinta(string otsikko)
    {
        this.teksti = otsikko;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C# creates a default constructor if you don't define one (which you didn't), and the default constructor has no arguments and doesn't do anything.  It's equivalent to this:

```
public Blogimerkinta()
{
}
```

In order to use a constructor which does take an argument (and I'm assuming internally set a property on the object to the value of that argument) you'll need to define one.  Something like this:

```
public Blogimerkinta(string teksti)
{
    this.Teksti = teksti;
}
```

(Or setting whatever value you want to set internally.  Currently your class has only one property of type `string` but the naming makes it very unclear if that's what you're trying to set.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are trying to create an instance of `Blogimerkinta` and passing a string parameter to the constructor.But, you don't have any constructor on your class that takes a string parameter.Either create a constructor or use default parameterless constructor to create your instance:

```
Blogimerkinta merkinta = new Blogimerkinta();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Blogimerkinta does not have a constructor defined for it. During compilation there will be a default one generated that takes no arguments. If you want your class to take an argument during instantiation, make a contructor that takes an argument.

```
 class Blogimerkinta
    {
        public Blogimerkinta(string foo){
         //do something with foo
        }
        string teksti;
        string[] avainsanat;

        public string Teksti { get; set; }
        public string[] Avainsanat { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This line calls constructor with one parameter.

`Blogimerkinta merkinta = new Blogimerkinta(otsikko);`

To fix this you have to create one.

```
class Blogimerkinta
{
    string teksti;
    string[] avainsanat;

    public Blogimerkinta(){} // This is parameterless constructor
    public Blogimerkinta(string input)
    {
        if(input != null)
            teksti = input; //You initialize class fields here or do other stuff
    }
    public string Teksti { get; set; }
    public string[] Avainsanat { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see in Main(), you are passing a `string` value, so that constructor must take a string value, to initialize its field/fields with that value (possibly more values)

Check the msdn, since they explain it quite good.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx

Comment: FYI: you don't need to test string `input` for null.

Comment: @NathanKoop well since `string` is reference type, it can be `null`, therefor nobody usually wants to work with `null`

Comment: but you're assigning a string to a string, so using your code, what will teksti be set to if input is null?

Comment: @NathanKoop to null, I know, but it is a good programming practice to test your input, because that string won't sit there without being used somewhere in that class.

Comment: cool, I do think it's a good practice to test your input's values (range & null), just was pointing out that in this particular case it wasn't doing anything specific.

Comment: @NathanKoop Well it wasn't, but since the OP is new to programming, he should learn good practices since beginning :)

Answer (score 1):

A class has 1 or more constructors. If you do not provide one, the compiler will create an empty one:
A constructor is called when you say 'new Blogimerkinta()'
You are calling a constructor that takes an argument: new Blogimerkinta(otsikko)
but you did not define a constructor.

You need to define this constructor:

```
public Blogimerkinta(string s) {
    teksti = s; //I don't know which field you want to assign, just an example
}
```

(So it looks a method, but without a return type and it has the same name as the class)

If you do not define a constructor, you can only call 'new Blogimerkinta()'

Answer (score -1):

Here is a generic fix:

```
class Blogimerkinta
    {
        string teksti;
        string[] avainsanat;
        string foo="";
        public Blogimerkinta(string bar)
        {
              foo=bar;
        }
        public string Teksti { get; set; }
        public string[] Avainsanat { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Since the OP needs to improve his OOP knowledge, you could improve your answer to add an explanation of the concepts involved (constructors), not only giving a working fix.